# Error when migrating django app on heroku bash

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

[Screenshot of heroku bash running on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjEcA.png)First of all, I deployed my django app on heroku. The site works well but when I try to interact with database (fill a form that submits input to db), I get a programming error. I learnt I needed to run a migrate command on heroku bash and did. After a few migrations it returned a lot of error lines, the first saying '..../django.db.backends.until.py, line 85, in _execute
         return self.cursor.execute(SQL, params)
        pyscopg2.DataError: integer out of range.
Then other lines of error saying the above error led to the others. How can I fix this please? Searched online but couldn't find it

PS if I run the migrate command cmd  in dev mode on my machine it works well.

```
#0004_auto_... file


from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('mainsite', '0003_auto_20181109_2333'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='contact',
        name='phone',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=20),
    ),
]
```

and then this is the affected model:

```
#models.py file

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeFiel``d(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +'(' + self.email +')'
```

Comment: One line of an error message isn’t enough information. Please show the full traceback, the migration file that is failing, and the related model.

Comment: @Alasdair added screenshot cos I cant copy error code on cmd

Comment: Please show the migration file (`mainsite/migrations/0002_auto_...py`) and the related models

Comment: @Alasdair code blocks added

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alasdair for your time, poked around the net more and found the reason. 
I ran `makemigrations` on heroku bash out for stupid curiousity. I should not have as it was what created those migrations file that gave me trouble. I ran `migrate` straight.